# Applying replace over a list of certain columns of a dataframe

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have a list with names of **30 columns in a dataframe**.

I have to apply replace to these 30 columns only.
I tried:

```
list = names(df[!,r"Com"]) - ok!
```

Then I am trying:

```
replace!(df[!,list],"RR" =>"AA") - Fail
```

How can I do such transformation(with certain columns at once)?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. In what I write below I assume you want to update the `df` data frame in-place (i.e. you do not want a new data frame, but change the existing one).

```
foreach(col -> replace!(col, "RR" => "AA"), eachcol(df[!, r"Com"]))
```

or

```
mapcols!(col -> replace!(col, "RR" => "AA"), df[!, r"Com"])
```

or

```
transform!(df, Cols(r"Com") .=> col -> replace!(col, "RR" => "AA"), renamecols=false)
```